# Trouble Grouping By Name

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm having trouble grouping by name (CC.Nome) in this query, can you help me out?

Here is my code:

```
SELECT  
    Registadas.CodigoVisualizado As Codigo, 
    CC.Nome as Entidade, 
    CC.Documento AS Documento, 
    CC.DataDocumento as DataDocumento, 
    ISNULL(ROUND((SELECT SUM(CASE 
                                WHEN tbCCEntidades.Natureza = 'R'
                                THEN  tbCCEntidades.TotalMoedaReferencia
                                ELSE -tbCCEntidades.TotalMoedaReferencia
                              END)
                  FROM tbCCEntidades
                  WHERE CC.IDEntidade = Entidades.ID), 2), 0) AS Saldo, 
    CC.Natureza As Natureza
FROM
    tbCCEntidades AS CC
INNER JOIN
    tbEntidades Entidades ON Entidades.ID = CC.IDEntidade
INNER JOIN
    tbEntidadesRegistadas Registadas ON Registadas.IDEntidade = Entidades.ID
```

What happens is that this query gives the rows mixed like this:

[image: Table problem here]

Comment: What exactly is the trouble?   Do you get an error?   If so, what is the exact error message?

Comment: @TabAlleman I'm having trouble in knowing where to put the "Group By" statement :/
 If I insert it inside the SUM Select it gives me this error:

"Each GROUP BY expression must contain at least one column that is not an outer reference."

Comment: What's wrong with the query the way it is?   Why do you think you need a GROUP BY at all?

Comment: Try at the end?

Group by Registadas.CodigoVisualizado, CC.Nome, CC.Documento,    CC.DataDocumento

Comment: By grouping by `CC.Nome` you'd probably get one result row per CCEntidade. But you are selecting `Registadas.CodigoVisualizado`. Which? Can't a CCEntidade have multiple Codigos? What are you actually trying to achieve? Show sample data and expected result.

Comment: @TabAlleman I've edited the post, you can see the problem in the link image above :)

Comment: Posting broken query without explanation of what you are trying to do will not help us help you.  Also I don't see any `GROUP BY` in your statement.

Comment: @Eric Yes, it was an error, and I apologise for that. The query works, it returns the data I need, the thing that I don't know is where to put the "Group By" in order to order the result by CC.Nome :/

Answer (score 1):

The real problem with your query is that you haven't correlated the sub-query properly:

```
    ISNULL(ROUND((
        SELECT SUM( CASE 
                        WHEN tbCCEntidades.Natureza = 'R'
                        THEN tbCCEntidades.TotalMoedaReferencia
                        ELSE - tbCCEntidades.TotalMoedaReferencia
                    END)
        FROM tbCCEntidades
        Where CC.IDEntidade = Entidades.ID ), 2), 0) AS Saldo,
```

In this FROM clause you didn't give an alias to the table, so in the WHERE clause neither of the sides of the filter is filtering the subquery.  Both `CC` and `Entidades` are in the outer query, so this subquery isn't being filtered at all:  It's getting the SUM of all rows in the entire table, every time.

I can't be sure of the fix just from this broken code.  I would guess instead of `CC` you need to alias the table in the subquery, and use that alias on the left side of the filter.

Since your sub-query just returns a SUM() it doesn't need a GROUP BY at all, and since it's in a subquery, the SUM() would not be improved by adding a GROUP BY to your main query.

Answer (score 0):

you have to put group by right after where conditions

like

```
select CC.Name,SUM(something) from TableName where SomeCondition group by CC.Name
```

and yes you have to put everything on select that is not a aggregate function in group by i would suggest you to go ahead with CTE expression.then make a join on other fields you needed from table.

Answer (score 0):

> The query works, it returns the data I need, the thing that I don't know is where to put the "Group By" in order to order the result by CC.Nome :/

You only want to sort your result rows? That's not `GROUP BY`, but `ORDER BY`:

```
...
ORDER BY Entidade;
```